# How can I add in field naming to a KeyValuePair in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
        var values1 = (EReferenceKey[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(EReferenceKey)); 
        var valuesWithNames = values1.Select(
            value => new {
                Value = ((int)value).ToString("00"),
                Text = Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), "([A-Z])", " $1").Trim() 
            });
```

Here's some code that was suggested on stackoverflow that can make this method generic:

```
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetValues2<T>() where T : struct {
        var t = typeof(T);
        if (!t.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("Not an enum type");
        return Enum.GetValues(t)
            .Cast<T>()
            .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                ((int)Enum.ToObject(t, x)).ToString("00"), 
                Regex.Replace(x.ToString(), "([A-Z])", " $1").Trim()
                ));
    }
```

It gives me almost the same result but it's missing the naming "Value" and "Text". Can someone suggest to me how I could modify the latter code to add these and still have the results come back in order?

I did try doing it myself but it gave me errors when I tried to add in the "Value =" and "Text =" to the select of the generic:

Error   6   The name 'Value' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a class, values of which wiil be returned:

```
public class YourValues
{
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;}
}
```

And modify like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<YourValues> GetValues2<T>() where T : struct 
{
    var t = typeof(T);
    if (!t.IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("Not an enum type");
    return Enum.GetValues(t)
        .Cast<T>()
        .Select(x => new YourValues{
            Value = ((int)Enum.ToObject(t, x)).ToString("00"), 
            Text = Regex.Replace(x.ToString(), "([A-Z])", " $1").Trim()
            });
}
```